# nginx server forward request on custom port to node app

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a VPS server running nginx and i also have a node app running on port 8000. The nginx server house my PHP application and runs well on default webserver port.

I have a custom domainame pointing to the server ip.

I have installed let's encrypt to handle my https traffic and it works for my php app.

i have to capture https traffic on port 8080 and forward the request to my node app on port 8000.

I have tried most of things stackoverflow. i dont know what i'm doing wrong.

Below is a copy of what my nginx server block looks like.

```
 server {
       listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/repairspots.org/fullchain.pem; # managed$
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/repairspots.org/privkey.pem; # manag$
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
    }




// i need to get this portion right

server {
  listen [::]:8080 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
  listen 8080 ssl;
  server_name 0.0.0.0;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem; # managed$
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem; # manag$
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

  error_page  497 https://0.0.0.0:8080$request_uri;

  # pass requests to port 8000 where our other node server is running
  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue with the below.

i created /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf and pasted the server block below.

```
server {
    listen 8080 ssl;
    listen [::]:8080 ssl ipv6only=on;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed$
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # manag$
  include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
  ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

  error_page 497  https://$host:$server_port$request_uri;#enforces https redirect on http traffic

   location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Ssl on; #needed incase redirects comes from http
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        rewrite ^/?(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000; #node server
        proxy_redirect off;

    }


}
```

This was the one thing i wasnt doing at all before. You need to accept internet traffic on the port you're listening on. run the below command inline with the port number.

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT
```